# how to get email address along with credential for calendar after user allow permission

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-authentication, google-developers-console, google-client

how to get owner email address after user allow permission

```
  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']  
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials.json, SCOPES)
  creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
  service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

> ```
>   event_body = {
>      'summary': 'Test calendar',
>     'location': 'Gurgaon, Haryana',
>     'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer 
>       products.',
>   'start': {
>     'dateTime': '2020-03-28T09:00:00-07:00',
>     'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata',
>     },
> 'end': {
>     'dateTime': '2020-03-28T17:00:00-07:00',
>     'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
>    },
>
> 'attendees': [
>     {'email': 'user@gmail.com'},
>    ],
> 'reminders': {
>     'useDefault': False,
>   },
> "visibility": "public",
>    }
> ```

```
 event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary',body=evnt_body)
```

Also tried to add 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' this scope but it returns None in credential.
My need to add owner user's email address in attendances list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a call to [Users.getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile), and provide the special value **me** to `userId` to indicate the authenticated user:

```py
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
email_address = gmail_service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()["emailAddress"]
```

#### Note:

- One of [these scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile#auth) has to be provided.
- Please notice that the user who creates the event is by default added as an attendee. You might not need to specify this user when creating the event.

#### Reference:

- [Gmail API: Users.getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

Comment: Hi Iamblichus big thanks for your providing solution it helped to reach my requirment
i have done it as
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

email_address = build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=self.creds).userinfo().get().execute()['email']

and added OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE in env to avoid scope change warning